# Content Panes in Java

Tags: java, swing, contentpane

I am  new to programming and was  just studying  JFrame etc ,  here i read   ContentPane  Like this  "Components go in the "content pane", not directly in the frame."  when  i did search COntentpane  i  read containment hierarch  that is pretty confusing for me to understand ,

Can some one  please  clear me the concept of ContentPane and  containment hierarchy of Gui Component

Comment: It's all explained in [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). What don't you understand?

Comment: for example we are  using  JFrame f= new JFrame();   and then      Container content = f.getContentPane();      content.add(new JButton("Button 1")); and same way it goes , why not  Directly  frame.add(button)  and so on ..  why we  add  content pane  here

Comment: Because that's what you're supposed to do, because it has been designed like that and documented. Just like to go faster with your car, you must press the right pedal and not the left one. You can add the components to the frame directly, though, because adding it to the frame actually adds it to the content pane for you.

Comment: Ok , that clears the idea  Thanks for help .

Answer (score 7):

I think this diagram describes distinctly what you want:

[image]

Comment: for example we are using  JFrame f= new JFrame();                    and then Container content = f.getContentPane(); content.add(new JButton("Button 1")); and same way it goes , why not Directly frame.add(button) and so on .. why we add contentpane here while it can be dont without   contentpane

Comment: @SikanderNawaz In newer Java version as a convenience, the `add` method and its variants, `remove` and `setLayout` have been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary.