# Why I obtain this error when I try to add the Container object to the main JFrame object using Swing?

Tags: java, swing, miglayout, jsr296

I am absolutly new in Java **Swing** application and I have the following problem.

I have this simple **LoginFrame2** class:

```
package com.test.login;

import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

import net.miginfocom.swt.MigLayout;

import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;

public class LoginFrame2 extends SingleFrameApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("DENTRO: LoginFrame() ---> main()");
        launch(LoginFrame2.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void startup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside startup()");

        JFrame mainFrame = this.getMainFrame();         // main JFrame that represents the Windows
        mainFrame.setTitle("XCloud Login");

        Container mainContainer = mainFrame.getContentPane();       // main Container into the main JFrame

        // JPanel creation and settings of the MigLayout on it:
        JPanel externalPanel = new JPanel();
        externalPanel.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout("fill"));

        externalPanel.add(new JLabel("Username"));

        mainContainer.add(externalPanel);
        mainFrame.add(mainContainer);


    }

}
```

As you can see I am using the **SingleFrameApplication** abstrac class of the **JDesktop** framework that simply provide to me one primary JFrame (this abstract class also takes care of component property injection, exit processing, and saving/restoring session state in a way that's appropriate for simple single-frame applications).

When the class is executed the **startUp()** method is executed.

As you can see I have performed the following operations:

1. I take the main **Jframe** using the **getMainFrame()** method and I put its reference into **mainFrame** variable
2. I take the main **Container** (that is into the mainFrame object) calling the **getContentPane()** method
3. Then I create a **JPanel** object named **externalPanel** in which I put an initialized **JLabel** that will show a string.
4. Finally I add my **JPanel** object to the **Container** object and then I try to add the **Container** to the main **JFrame** object.

The problem is that when I execute this class I obtain the following error message:

```
DENTRO: LoginFrame() ---> main()
Inside startup()
8-nov-2013 12.35.23 org.jdesktop.application.Application$1 run
GRAVE: Application class com.test.login.LoginFrame2 failed to launch
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself
    at java.awt.Container.checkAddToSelf(Container.java:418)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1036)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:957)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:540)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:363)
    at com.test.login.LoginFrame2.startup(LoginFrame2.java:38)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:187)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:642)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Application class com.test.login.LoginFrame2 failed to launch
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:192)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:642)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself
    at java.awt.Container.checkAddToSelf(Container.java:418)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1036)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:957)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:540)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:363)
    at com.test.login.LoginFrame2.startup(LoginFrame2.java:38)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:187)
    ... 14 more
```

I think that the problem is the adding of the Container object in its Jframe object. But why? From what I have understand the Container object is the object wrapped inside the JFrame...where is the problem? how can I solve it?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: my question, why bothering with refused framework, there are a few limitations, e.g. isn't possible to change JFrames Icons, and another more than funny bugs

Comment: are you speacking about JDesktop or MigLayout?

Comment: about JSR296 - JDesktop,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are triying add container in this container. Problem is here

```
Container mainContainer = mainFrame.getContentPane();
...
mainFrame.add(mainContainer);
```

this `JFrame mainFrame = this.getMainFrame();` already have `ContentPane`, and you adding one more. Each JFrame have 3 panels -> glassPane, contentPane and layerdPane.

Try add elements in `mainContainer` (that already included in `mainFrame`).

Comment: mmm so when I call the getContentPane() method I am putting the reference of the Container object that is into the mainJframe object into the mainContainer variable. So if I add a JPane object to this mainContainer object I will have it also in the mainFrame object, is it right?

Comment: yep. read more about it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553315/content-panes-in-java) on image

Answer (score 2):

mainContainer is already derived from the JFrame.

```
JFrame mainFrame = this.getMainFrame();         
    // main JFrame that represents the Windows
mainFrame.setTitle("XCloud Login");

Container mainContainer = mainFrame.getContentPane();
 ..
mainFrame.add(mainContainer);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mainContainer = mainFrame.getContentPane();
//...
mainFrame.add(mainContainer);//wrong
```

There's no reaqson to add **mainContainer** back to **mainFrame**, and adding children to a JFrame is completely wrong in general.

You should simply add children to **mainContainer**, as you already do.